# SET ANSI_NULLS is not working

Tags: sql-server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT NULL AS ID, 'XYZ' AS NAME) TABLE1
INNER JOIN (SELECT NULL AS ID, 'ABC' AS NAME) TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
```

After setting `ANSII_NULLS OFF`, I am not getting correct output

Comment: If you need this you can use `ON EXISTS (SELECT TABLE1.ID INTERSECT SELECT TABLE2.ID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting correct output. You just aren't getting the output you expected.

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) is quite clear that the `ANSI_NULLS` setting only applies to literal comparisons to `NULL`. From that page:

> SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is NULL or a literal NULL. If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison.